# Как увеличить/уменьшить цифру, которая указана в input по нажатию кнопки в ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, input, click

Я новичок в изучении ReactJS и столкнулся с такой задачей:
Необходимо реализовать некое подобие функционала корзины онлайн-магазина. Рендерится некий компонент с карточкой товара `Card` и там есть поле `input` со значением "1" по умолчанию и кнопки "плюс" и "минус".

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  less() {
    ??????
  };

  more() {
    ??????
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product__count">
        <p className="product__count-title">Количество</p>
        <button onClick={this.less} className="product__btn-minus">-</button>
        <input className="product__count-input" value="1" />
        <button onClick={this.more} className="product__btn-plus">+</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Card />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Я попытался прописать две функции `less()` и `more()` и навесить их вызов на события `onClick` соответствующих кнопок, но у меня никак не получается в функциях получить значение, введенное в поле input и увеличить/уменьшить его...
В каком направлении хоть копать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

Comment: Значение input должно храниться в объекте state и браться оттуда (почитайте про state в React), а при вызовах функций должны вызываться методы setState и менять значения в state

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее! Сработало!)

Comment: пожалуйста, рад помочь